# Link Java textbox to string in external class

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a project in which I have a Java GUI class and another class which contains its relevant methods.

I want a text area in the GUI to be updated with the content of a string in the other class whenever it changes. What is the easiest way to watch for these changes?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for data binding. Java unfortunately has no own support for that, but there are several libraries to choose from, like for example [JGoodies data binding](https://binding.dev.java.net/).

If you want to roll your own, there's the ubiquitous observer pattern which you doubtless already know from Swing :). Just add listener support to the class holding the strings and add a listener to it that updates the text area, when an event comes.

Answer (score 1):

Make the "other class" a proper bean that supports PropertyChangeListeners. Then create a PropertyChangeLister which acts on changes in the "other class" and which updates the textarea.

Something like this:

```
otherClass.addPropertyChangeListener("propertyname", new PropertyChangeListener() {
   void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
     textarea.setText(evt.getNewValue());
   }
}
```

See

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/properties/bound.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BeansBinding](https://beansbinding.dev.java.net)

It does almost exactly what you need.  Only thing is that your otherClass must support Java Beans listeners, as described by @ordnungswidrig